# How to write a duplicate mapping function?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I need a function `MapDuplicate` that maps a function on all the duplicates in a list.

Consider the following list:

```
list={"f1","f2","f1","f3","f2","f1","f4"};
MapDuplicate[f,list]
```

would return

```
{f["f1",1],f["f2",1],f["f1",2],"f3",f["f2",2],f["f1",3],"f4"}
```

One obvious application of this functionality would be to rename duplicate items:

```
f[x_,n_]:=x<>"_"<>ToString@n;
```

Now `MapDuplicate[f,list]` would return non-colliding field names:

```
{"f1_1","f2_1","f1_2","f3","f2_2","f1_3","f4"}
```

Is there a simple way to write `MapDuplicate` using some `builtin` or `function repository` functions?

Comment: I have a pain in my arm up-voting all the good answers to this one!

Answer (score 5):

```
mapDuplicate[f_] := Module[{$c}, $c[_] = 0; 
  Map[x |-> If[Counts[#] @ x == 1, x, f[x, ++$c[x]]]] @ #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"};

mapDuplicate[foo] @ list
```

> ```
> {foo["f1", 1], foo["f2", 1], foo["f1", 2], "f3",   
>  foo["f2", 2], foo["f1", 3], "f4"}
> ```

```
mapDuplicate[# <> "_" <> ToString @ #2 &] @ list
```

> ```
>  {"f1_1", "f2_1", "f1_2", "f3", "f2_2", "f1_3", "f4"}
> ```

Comment: this produces `foo["f3", 1]` instead of `"f3"`

Comment: Thank you @I.M. I misread the question.

Comment: @I.M., updated with a fix.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
MapDuplicate[fn_, list_List] := MapIndexed[
  If[Count[list, #1] == 1
    , #1
    , fn[#1, Count[list[[1 ;; First@#2]], #1]]
    ] &
  , list
  ]

list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"};

MapDuplicate[g, list]
```

{g["f1", 1], g["f2", 1], g["f1", 2], "f3", g["f2", 2],
g["f1", 3], "f4"}

Answer (score 4):

```
indexDuplicates[f_] := Module[{$c}, $c[_] = 0; 
    # /. x_ /; Counts[#]@x > 1 :> f[x, ++$c[x]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
indexDuplicates[foo]@list
```

> ```
> {foo["f1", 1], foo["f2", 1], foo["f1", 2], "f3", foo["f2", 2], 
>  foo["f1", 3], "f4"}
> ```

```
indexDuplicates[# <> "_" <> ToString@#2 &]@list
```

> ```
> {"f1_1", "f2_1", "f1_2", "f3", "f2_2", "f1_3", "f4"}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
MapAt[f,#,List/@Cases[PositionIndex[#],x_/;Length[x]>1:>Sequence@@x]]&@list

(* {f[f1],f[f2],f[f1],f3,f[f2],f[f1],f4} *)
```

**mapAtDuplicates**

```
mapAtDuplicates:=Function[{list,fn},ReplacePart[list,First@#1->fn[#2,
  Last@#1]&@@@Thread[{#2,#1}]&@@@(MapAt[MapIndexed[{#1,First@#2}&],
  {2}]/@(KeyValueMap[List]@(Select[PositionIndex[list], Length[#]>1&])))//Flatten]]
```

```
mapAtDuplicates[list,{#1,#2}&]

(* {{f1,1},{f2,1},{f1,2},f3,{f2,2},{f1,3},f4} *)
```

```
mapAtDuplicates[list,#1[#2]&]

(* {f1[1],f2[1],f1[2],f3,f2[2],f1[3],f4}  *)
```

```
mapAtDuplicates[list,#1<>"_"<>ToString[#2]&]

(* {f1_1,f2_1,f1_2,f3,f2_2,f1_3,f4} *)
```

##### Just for Fun: Map Duplicates in a Protein Sequence

(i) Import a sequence (bovine serum albumin, 607 amino acids, single letter code)

```
importedSequence = Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=3336842&rettype=fasta&retmode=text", "Data"];
 
{bsaSequenceHeading, bsaSequenceData} = {#[[1,1]], #[[2,1]]} &@importedSequence;
```

(ii) Map Duplicates

```
Short[mapAtDuplicates[StringSplit[bsaSequenceData,""],#1[#2]&],10]

(* 
{M[1],K[1],W[1],V[1],T[1],F[1],I[1],S[1],L[1],L[2],
 L[3],L[4],F[2],S[2],S[3],A[1],Y[1],S[4],R[1],G[1],
 V[2],F[3],R[2],R[3],D[1],T[2],H[1],K[2],S[5],E[1],
 I[2],A[2],H[2],R[4],F[4],K[3],D[2],L[5],<<531>>,V[33],M[5],
 E[57],N[14],F[28],V[34],A[41],F[29],V[35],D[38],K[58],C[33],
 C[34],A[42],A[43],D[39],D[40],K[59],E[58],A[44],C[35],F[30],
 A[45],V[36],E[59],G[17],P[28],K[60],L[64],V[37],V[38],S[32],
 T[34],Q[20],T[35],A[46],L[65],A[47] } *)
```

But a criticism of this approach might be that only duplicates are indexed.

(iii) Import a sequence with singletons (Insulin B chain)

```
importedSequenceTwo = Import["http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=2WS1_B&rettype=fasta&retmode=text", "Data"];

{insulinBChainHeading, insulinBChainData} = {#[[1,1]], #[[2,1]]} &@importedSequenceTwo;
```

(iv) Map Duplicates

```
mapAtDuplicates[StringSplit[insulinBChainData,""], #1[#2]&]


(* 
 {F[1],V[1],N,Q,H[1],L[1],C[1],G[1],S,H[2],
  L[2],V[2],E[1],A,L[3],Y,L[4],V[3],C[2],G[2],
  E[2],R,G[3],F[2],F[3],X,T[1],P,K,T[2]} 
*)
```

**cumIndex**

```
cumIndex:=Function[list,ReplacePart[list,First@#1->#2[Last@#1]&@@@Thread[
  {#2,#1}]&@@@(MapAt[MapIndexed[{#1,First@#2}&],{2}]/@(KeyValueMap[List]@(
  PositionIndex[list])))//Flatten]]
```

(v) Cumulative Index

```
cumIndex[StringSplit[insulinBChainData,""]]

(*      
 {F[1],V[1],N[1],Q[1],H[1],L[1],C[1],G[1],S[1],H[2],
  L[2],V[2],E[1],A[1],L[3],Y[1],L[4],V[3],C[2],G[2],
  E[2],R[1],G[3],F[2],F[3],X[1],T[1],P[1],K[1],T[2]} 
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`SubsetMap` will allow you to apply a function to a subset of a list. The function you give to `SubsetMap` to apply to the subset must work on a list and return a list of the same length.

So, starting with your list,

```
list={"f1","f2","f1","f3","f2","f1","f4"};
```

we could try to come up with a function that, when given a list of strings (which we know will be duplicates) returns a list of where the elements are disambiguated in some fashion. I'll choose to do the disambiguation by appending an index.

```
RenameByIndex[alist : {__String}] := MapIndexed[#1 <> ToString[#2[[1]]] &, alist]
```

So, we're part way there:

```
SubsetMap[RenameByIndex, {1, 2, 3}][list]
(* {"f11", "f22", "f13", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"} *)
```

Of course, `{1,2,3}` isn't where the duplicates are, that was just a demo. So now we need to get indices for duplicates. `PositionIndex` can get us something useful:

```
PositionIndex[list]
(* <|f1->{1,3,6},f2->{2,5},f3->{4},f4->{7}|> *)
```

We can get a `SubsetMap` function by mapping over the values of that structure:

```
SubsetMap[RenameByIndex, #] & /@ Values[PositionIndex[list]]
(* {SubsetMap[RenameByIndex,{1,3,6}],SubsetMap[RenameByIndex,{2,5}],SubsetMap[RenameByIndex,{4}],SubsetMap[RenameByIndex,{7}]} *)
```

Now, that's just a bunch of individual functions. We need to turn that into one function that we can apply to our list. That's a job for `Composition`:

```
RenameDuplicates = 
  Composition @@ (SubsetMap[RenameByIndex, #] & /@ Values[PositionIndex[list]])
```

Let's try it out:

```
RenameDuplicates[list]
(* {"f11", "f21", "f12", "f31", "f22", "f13", "f41"} *)
```

Okay, this renamed singletons too. So, we should delete those cases from the position index step:

```
RenameDuplicates = 
  Composition @@ (SubsetMap[RenameByIndex, #] & /@ DeleteCases[Values[PositionIndex[list]], {_}])
```

And we really don't want to hard code this to the exact list you provided as an example, so:

```
RenameDuplicates[list : {__String}] := 
  (Composition @@ (SubsetMap[RenameByIndex, #] & /@ 
    DeleteCases[Values[PositionIndex[list]], {_}]))[list]
```

Now, this has all been based on the idea of deduping strings, but your comments suggest maybe your list won't always be strings. So, you'll need to adapt this to whatever deduping strategy you want to use in the non-string context. Specifically, you'll need something different for the `RenameByIndex` function.

Answer (score 3):

A basic approach:

```
list={"f1","f2","f1","f3","f2","f1","f4"};


w[n_] := With[{x = list[[n]]}, f[x, Count[list[[1 ;; n]], x]]]
Table[w[j], {j, Length[list]}]
```

yields:

> f["f1", 1], f["f2", 1], f["f1", 2], f["f3", 1], f["f2", 2],   f["f1",
> 3], f["f4", 1]}

Answer (score 3):

```
mapAtDuplicates[f_] := Module[{$c}, $c[_] = 0;
   MapApply[If[$c[#] == 1, #, f @ ##] &] @* Map[{#, ++$c[#]} &]];
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"};

mapAtDuplicates[h] @ list
```

> ```
>  {h["f1", 1], h["f2", 1], h["f1", 2], "f3", h["f2", 2], h["f1", 3], "f4"}
> ```

```
mapAtDuplicates[# <> "_" <> ToString @ #2 &] @ list
```

> ```
>  {"f1_1", "f2_1", "f1_2", "f3", "f2_2", "f1_3", "f4"}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1];
rlst = RandomInteger[10, 15];

Grid[{rlst, mapAtDuplicates[Subscript]@rlst}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"};

mapDuplicates[f_, list_] := Module[{m}, m[_] = 0;
  duplicates = Select[list, Counts[list][#] > 1 &];
  (m[#]++; If[MemberQ[duplicates, #], f[#, m[#]], #]) & /@ list]

mapDuplicates[f, list]
```

> {f["f1", 1], f["f2", 1], f["f1", 2], "f3", f["f2", 2],
> f["f1", 3], "f4"}

Answer (score 2):

```
list={"f1","f2","f1","f3","f2","f1","f4"}  ; 

ClearAll[map] ;
map[fn_, list_]:=Block[
    {counts, keys},
    counts = DeleteCases[Counts[list], 1] ;
    keys = Keys[counts] ;
    Reverse[Table[If[MemberQ[keys, key], fn[key, counts[key]--], key], {key, Reverse[list]}]]
] ;
list
map[fn, list]

(* {"f1","f2","f1","f3","f2","f1","f4"} *)
(* {fn["f1",1],fn["f2",1],fn["f1",2],"f3",fn["f2",2],fn["f1",3],"f4"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"}

Module[{c = <|# -> 1 & /@ Union[list]|>}, g @@ {#, c[#]++} & /@ list]
```

{g["f1", 1], g["f2", 1], g["f1", 2], g["f3", 1], g["f2", 2],
g["f1", 3], g["f4", 1]}

Answer (score 2):

Quite basic.  Easy to follow, hopefully.

```
MapDuplicate[t_] := Module[{d, s, p},

  d = First /@ DeleteCases[Tally[t], {_, 1}];

  s = f[#, 0] & /@ d;

  If[(p = Position[d, #]) == {}, #,
     p = p[[1, 1]];
     s[[p, 2]] += 1;
     s[[p]]] & /@ t
  ]

MapDuplicate[list]
```

> {f["f1", 1], f["f2", 1], f["f1", 2], "f3", f["f2", 2],
> f["f1", 3], "f4"}

Answer (score 1):

My attempt is the following:

```
MapDuplicates[func_, list_List] := 
Module[{resultList = {}, occurrences = <||>, duplicates}, 
duplicates = Select[DeleteDuplicates[list], Count[list, #] > 1 &];
Scan[(If[MemberQ[duplicates, #], 
occurrences[#] = 
If[KeyExistsQ[occurrences, #], occurrences[#] + 1, 1];
AppendTo[resultList, func[#, occurrences[#]]];, 
AppendTo[resultList, #];]) &, list]; resultList]
```

Testing `MapDuplicates`:

```
f[x_, n_] := x <> "_" <> ToString@n;
list = {"f1", "f2", "f1", "f3", "f2", "f1", "f4"};
MapDuplicates[f, list]

(*{"f1_1", "f2_1", "f1_2", "f3", "f2_2", "f1_3", "f4"}*)
```

Comment: Elements in the list don't have to be strings, also certainly not the same length.

Comment: See the update, please!

Answer (score 1):

This works if the output doesn't need to be in the same order as the input list:

```
MapDuplicate[f_, list_] := 
 Flatten[If[#[[2]] > 1, Table[f[#[[1]], n], {n, #[[2]]}], #[[1]]] & /@
    Tally[list]]

MapDuplicate[g, list]
```

> {g["f1", 1], g["f1", 2], g["f1", 3], g["f2", 1],
> g["f2", 2], "f3", "f4"}

```
f[x_, n_] := x <> "_" <> ToString@n;
MapDuplicate[f, list]
```

> {"f1_1", "f1_2", "f1_3", "f2_1", "f2_2", "f3", "f4"}